# How to trigger a Git-webhook to merge any protetcted github branch to a test branch via Jenkinsfile?

Tags: linux, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, git-webhooks

I have built a jenkins pipeline using jenkinsfile which basically runs pylint and unit tests on my test branch (let's say "devops" branch). Now i want to merge this test-branch, **devops** to my **master** branch which is a **protected branch** i.e I cannot merge these two branches locally and then do a direct push to this master branch.

I read about git-webhooks and **i am thinking to trigger a webhook from my jenkinfile (via available plugin, if any) that might create a pull-request for merge in github and then i can review the changes and permit for merge via manual click.**

I don't know the exact procedure and resources to implement this. Any lead woud be apreciated.